# Explain void (*signal(int signo, void *(func)(int)))(int)

Tags: c, linux, function, signals

Please explain this type signature : `void (*signal(int signo, void *(func)(int)))(int)`

Comment: Whats this (int) thing at the end?

Comment: Why was my question down voted?

Comment: Syntax error: http://www.cdecl.org/ What is the actual declaration?

Comment: You should ask the question in the question body, not the title.  It just feels weird to have the question: "Please explain this function parameter".

Comment: Which function parameter?  You are showing the declaration of a function that takes two parameters.  Which one do you want explained?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The type signature of the `signal` function is a bit more clear when a typedef is used for the function pointers that are passed around:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal(int signo, sighandler_t func);
```

`sighandler_t` is a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns nothing. The `signal` function takes such a function pointer as its second parameter. It also returns a function pointer of that type.

Answer (score 1):

C declarations need to be read from the inside out.  The tricky part with complex function declarations is figuring out which is the innermost declarator (where to start).  Its generally the first identifier that is not a type identifier.  So in this case:

```
void (*signal(int signo, void *(func)(int)))(int)
```

the declarator is `signal`.  Within the parenthesis, suffixes are higher precedence than prefixes, so `signal` is a function taking two args (the `(int signo, void *(func)(int))` part), that returns a pointer (the prefix `*`) to a function taking a single int arg (the `(int)` on the end), and returning `void`