# Spiral rule and 'declaration follows usage' for parsing C and C++ declarations

Tags: c++, c, declaration

This question follows [this other question about C declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcint). Reading the answer to this question, I read about the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and I also understood what "declaration follows usage" means.

Ok so far. But then I read [this declaration](http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html):

```
char *(*(*a[N])())();
```

and I was wondering how to parse it with the "declaration follows usage" 'rule'. Especially for the array part.

What I read is:

```
(*(*a[N])())
```

is a function `()` returning a `char *`, then, dereferencing the following

```
(*a[N])() // 1
```

is this 'function returning a `char*`', and so 1 is a 'pointer to a function returning `char *`'
  then I would say 'when `(*a[N])` is called, it is [previous declaration]'. At this point we have `(*a[N])` is a function returning a pointer to a function returning `char *`.

But then I don't know how to apply this rule to distinguish between the 'pointer to array' and 'array of pointer'.

Can someone clarify this?

Other question: what are the rules of "precedence" in such declarations, between `&` (in C++), `*`, and `[]`? [maybe "precedence" is not the correct term]

---

To check if I understood the 'spiral rule' correctly, I also parse this expression below; please tell me if I am wrong.

```
       +-----------+
       | +------+  |
       | | +-+  |  |
       | | ^ |  |  |
char* (*(* a[N])())(); 
    ^  ^ ^   ^  ^  ^
    |  | |   |  |  |
    |  | +---+  |  |
    |  +--------+  |
    +--------------+
```

For me it is easier (loop by loop):

- `a` is an array of N ...
- pointer to function returning ...
- pointer to function returning ...
- `char *`

But I am maybe missing something which in that case let me obtain the correct answer but that could be wrong in another more complicated case.

Comment: @Vality: If you're going to drop the C++ tag, you need to drop the mention of `&` in C++ too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point, Normally I would say this needs to be split into two questions, but its such an old question I am reluctant to do so.

Comment: @Vality How come the question suddenly got so much attention? (I was notified for the 'nice question' badge).

Comment: @CedricH. I suspect it is because the in-progress vote to flag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762/ as a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just have to build it up in steps.

```
char *X();  // X =~ (*(*a[N])())
```

Function returning `char*`

```
char *(*Y())();  // Y =~ (*a[N])
```

Function returning pointer to function returning `char*`.

In a declaration, just as in an expression (declaration follow usage), postfix `[]` has a higher precedence that unary `*` so `*a[N]` is equivalent to `*(a[N])`, not `(*a)[N]`.

```
char *(*(*Z)())();  // Z =~ a[N]
```

Pointer to function returning pointer to function returning `char*`.

```
char *(*(*a[N])())();
```

Array of N pointers to functions returning a pointer to function returning `char*`.