# Easy rule to read complicated const declarations?

Tags: c++, c, constants, declaration

For reading complex pointer declarations there is the [right-left rule](https://web.archive.org/web/20110818081319/http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html).

But this rule does not mention how to read `const` modifiers.

For example in a simple pointer declaration, `const` can be applied in several ways:

```
char *buffer; // non-const pointer to non-const memory
const char *buffer; // non-const pointer to const memory
char const *buffer; // equivalent to previous declartion
char * const buffer = {0}; // const pointer to non-const memory
char * buffer const = {0}; // error
const char * const buffer = {0}; // const pointer to const memory
```

Now what about the use of `const` with a pointer of pointer declaration?

```
char **x; // no const;
const char **x;
char * const *x;
char * * const x;
const char * const * x;
const char * * const x;
const char * const * const x;
```

And what is an easy rule to read those declarations?
Which declarations make sense?

Is the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) applicable?

### Two real world examples

The method [`ASTUnit::LoadFromCommandLine`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html#ab18e63a754071c368a0afccbec0de8a8) uses `const char **` to supply command line arguments (in the llvm clang source).

The argument vector parameter of [`getopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) is declared like this:

```
int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

Where `char * const argv[]` is equivalent to `char * const * argv` in that context.

Since both functions use the same concept (a vector of pointers to strings to supply the arguments) and the declarations differ - the obvious questions are: Why do they differ? Makes one more sense than the other?

The intend should be: The `const` modifier should specify that the function does not manipulate strings of this vector and does not change the structure of the vector.

Comment: Did this one not help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-expressions

Comment: Try the section on "Type Qualifiers" here:  https://www.bookofbrilliantthings.com/book/eic/the-golden-rule-of-pointers

Comment: My blog at bookofbrilliantthings.com is gone now, but you can still see the article above at https://web.archive.org/web/20130923181335/http://www.bookofbrilliantthings.com/book/eic/the-golden-rule-of-pointers

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The `const` modifier is trivial: it modifies what precedes it, unless
nothing precedes it.  So:

```
char const* buffer;  // const modifies char
char* const buffer;  // const modifies *
```

, etc.  Generally, It's best to avoid the forms where nothing precedes
the `const`, but in practice, you're going to see them, so you have to
remember that when no type precedes the `const`, you have to logically
move it behind the first type.  So:

```
const char** buffer;
```

is in fact:

```
char const** buffer;
```

, i.e. pointer to pointer to const char.

Finally, in a function declaration, a `[]` after reads as a `*` before.
(Again, it's probably better to avoid this misleading notation, but
you're going to see it, so you have to deal with it.)  So:

```
char * const argv[],  //  As function argument
```

is:

```
char *const * argv,
```

a pointer to a const pointer to a char.

Comment: @Vorac A frequently cited simplification, which only works for a few simple cases.

Comment: James Kanze, please, if you find the time, explain this in the [quesion I opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rula-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error)

Answer (score 8):

(Trying to focus on other aspects of the question)

The [rule of thumb for const declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#C.2B.2B_syntax) is to read them from right to left and `const` modifies the next token. Exception: At the beginning of a declaration `const` modifies the previous token.

There is a [rationale behind this exception](http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/cpp/const.qualifier.html) - for elementary declarations `const char c` looks for some people more natural than `char const c` - and it is reported that a precursor form of `const char c` predates the final const rule.

### getopt

```
int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

or

```
int getopt(int argc, char * const * argv, const char *optstring);
```

Which means that `argv` is a pointer to const vector of pointers to non-const strings.

But one would expect following declaration:

```
int getopt(int argc, char const * const * argv, const char *optstring);
```

(pointer to const vector to const strings)

Because `getopt()` is not supposed to change the strings referenced via argv.

At least `char **` (as used in `main()`) automatically converts to `char * const * argv`.

### Clang

```
ASTUnit::LoadFromCommandLine(...,  const char **argv, ...);
```

Which means that `argv` is a pointer to a non-const array of pointers to const strings.

Again one would expect `const char * const *argv` for the same reason as above.

But this is more noticeable because `char **` [does not convert](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17) to `const char **`, e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const char **x = argv; // Compile error!
  return 0;
}
```

yields a compile error, where

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char * const *x = argv;
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const char * const *x = argv;
  return 0;
}
```

do not.

Comment: @bobc, I wrote 'is to read them from right to left' - i.e. this is a reverse iteration. Thus, the choices of  'next' and 'previous' are correct. You seem to interpret those adjective in forward iterative sense - which does not make any sense in that context/paragraph. Hope that clears it up. Why do you think that this platform is crap? Because of answers like mine? Or comments like yours?