# What is (void (**) ()) and how to typedef it?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef, interrupt

In an embedded code I have to understand, there's this line of code :

```
*((void (**) ()) 0x01) = c_int01; /* Write the interrupt routine entry */
```

I can grasp the fact that you setup the interruption vector with the function pointer `c_int01`, but I can't figure what kind of cast `(void (**) ())` refers to. I know the standard function pointer notation `(void (*)())` but not the other one.

I tried to refactor the code so that it looked a bit more readable like this:

```
// header
typedef void (*interrupt_handler)(); // prototype of an interruption handler
#define INTERRUPT_VECTOR 0x01
#define SET_INTERRUPT_HANDLER( handler ) *((interrupt_handler) INTERRUPT_VECTOR) = (handler)

// code
SET_INTERRUPT_HANDLER( c_int01 );
```

But the embedded compiler whines about the LHS not beeing an object.

Anybody know what this notation signifies? `(void (**)())`

// EDIT:

For those interrested, I would understand this much better:

```
*( (void (*)())* 0x01) = c_int01;
```

Comment: Its a pointer to a pointer to a function.

Comment: MAAAANNN, how didn't I see that... I get it.

Comment: Unless your platform has `sizeof(void(*)()) == 1` or the vector table begins at an odd address, `0x01` can't be right.

Comment: I confirm, `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) == 1 == 32bits` on my platform (embedded DSP).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a pointer-to-pointer-to-function.

So the cast converts the integer `0x01` to the address of a function pointer having type `(void (*)())`

You could rewrite it:

```
typedef void (*interrupt_handler)();
*((interrupt_handler*) 0x01) = c_int101;
```

Comment: This is way more readable. `**` seems overkill, whereas `(void (*)() )*` is much much clearer.

Answer (score 6):

`(void (**) ())` is a pointer to a function pointer.

(`(void (*)())` is a pointer to a function, so adding a star adds a level of indirection.)

You need to say:

```
*((interrupt_handler*) INTERRUPT_VECTOR) = (handler)
```

That reads, *"Treat `INTERRUPT_VECTOR` as a pointer to a function pointer, and set its value to `handler`."*

Comment: Gotcha, Steve was the first to answer so I'll get his answer. Yours get my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the ever-useful [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says about the core of that expression, the `(void (**) ())`:

> cast unknown_name into pointer to pointer to function returning void

So, it's a cast (as signified by the outer pair of parentheses), and the type is "pointer to pointer to function", which seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) would be the quicker way to know:

```
     cast unknown_name into pointer to pointer to function returning void
```

The famous "spiral rule would be the next:

```
          +-----+
          |+-+  |
          || |  V
   (void (** |)( ))
      ^   ^^||  |
      |   ||||  |
      |   ||+|  |
      |   +--+  |
      +---------+
```

Following the lines you read:

- a pointer to
- a pointer to
- a function returning
- void

Comment: You have to tell me more about this spiral rule of yours!

Comment: @xgbi: Don't worry too much about the [spiral rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error)

Comment: I've learned it many years ago from a magazine (Computer Magazine for the ones old enough to remember it) it's also in the comp.lang.c FAQ: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 0):

You may visualize the setting of interrupt entry point vector as

```
   void (*interupt_handlers)()[256] = 0;

   void set_interupt_handler(int vector, void(*handler)())
   {
       interupt_handlers[vector] = handler;
   }
```