# How to decipher complex pointer declarations in C?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

So I want to give an example:

```
int *pi; // pi is a pointer that points to an integer
const int *cpi; // cpi is a pointer that points to a constant integer
char *pc; // pc is a pointer to a char
```

How can I read these:

```
char **x; //x is a pointer to a char pointer?
char *y[];
char **z[];
```

Thanks.

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org)

Comment: @BillLynch Not really correct I think. Should not this be char *titles[] equal to char **titles; ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: @BillLynch And, so??

Comment: @KorayTugay If it's a declaration with an initializer, as in `char *title[] = { "Title1", "Title2" };`, then "declare titles as array of pointer to char" is correct. If it's a function parameter, then the declaration would still state "array of pointer to char" because array notation was used, even though the array decays into a pointer, so it's still correct.

Comment: `char *titles[]` and `char ** titles` are two different types. They're not the same. That link describes a few ways in which they are different.

Comment: @BillLynch: Depends where it is placed. In a function's parameter list `T * t[]` is equal to `T ** t`.

Comment: @alk: And the code in the question has semicolons after each declaration. So they are declarations and not function arguments.

Comment: @BillLynch; What if I want to write a program like `cdecl.org`?

Comment: @haccks I think he is looking for a link to answer that :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sup>[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) is often linked to such questions. No doubt that it make easier to decipher any complex declaration, but at the same time it just provide an abstracted information. Being a C or C++ programmer one should know how to decipher complex declaration manually. [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) help to some extent but fails in some [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265389/2455888). This answer will help programmers to decipher any complex declaration manually.</sup>

---

Remember these two simple rules:

1. Always read declaration from the **inside out**.
2. When there is a choice, always favor `[]` and `()` over `*`.

The first rule simply states that, locate the variable that is being declared and start deciphering the declaration from it.

For second rule, if `*` precedes the identifier and `[]` or `()` follows it, then the identifier represents an array or function (respectively), not a pointer.

**Example 1:**

```
char *y[5];
```

- Variable/identifier is `y`.
- `*` precedes `y` and follows `[]`.
- `y` must be an array.

Combining above deciphering will result in: **`y` is an array of `5` pointers to `char`**.

Also note that you can always use parentheses to override the normal priority of `[]` or `()`.

**Example 2:**

```
void (*pf) (int);
```

- Variable/identifier is `pf`.
- `*pf` is enclosed in parenthesis, it must be a pointer.
- `()` follows `*pf`, means `pf` must points to a function.
- Since `()` encloses `int`, function must expects an argument of type `int`.

So, **`pf` is a pointer to function that expects an `int` argument and returns nothing**.

Now, what would you get after deciphering the following declaration

```
int *(*a[5])(void);
```

?

**Answer:**

> `a` is an array of pointers to functions that expects no argument and returning pointer to `int`.

---

**Note:**
Note that both of

```
char *y[];
char **z[];
```

will cause compilation error if they are not declared as arguments of a function. If they are function's argument then `char *y[]` is equivalent to `char **y` and `char **z[]` is equivalent to `char ***z`.
If that's not the case, then you need to specify the dimension as I did in my first example.

Answer (score 5):

Some example C declarations taken from the HELPPC utility (by David Jurgens) that saved my (programming) life back in the nineties (online version of the utility here: http://stanislavs.org/helppc )

```
int i;                  i as an int
int *i;                 i as a pointer to an int
int **i;                i is a pointer to a pointer to an int
int *(*i)();            i is a pointer to a function returning a
                          pointer to int
int *(*i[])();          i is an array of pointers to functions
                          returning pointers to an int
int *i[5];              i is an array of 5 pointers to int
int (*i)[5];            i is a pointer to an array of 5 ints
int *i();               i is a function returning a pointer to an int
int (*i)();             i is a pointer to a function returning int
int *(*(*i)())[5]       i is a pointer to a function returning a
                          pointer to an array of 5 pointers to an int
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` is an array of pointers to char, `z` is an array of pointers to pointer to char. `x` is a pointer to pointer to char

Comment: Why do you think `y` is an array of pointers to `char`? To me, it look like `y` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
char **x; //x is a pointer to a pointer to char
char *y[]; // y is an array of pointers to char
char **z[]; // z is an array of pointers to pointers to char
```

Comment: in general, the easiest way to read such expressions is to start at the right end and read to the left end

Comment: @KorayTugay, the definition of 'x' does not indicate that there will be multiple characters nor that the multiple characters will be terminated with a NUL byte.   However context may show that to be true.

Comment: `y` is not an array of `char` pointers. It will cause compilation error. Same for `z`.