# Understanding declaration in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am reading C++ in easy steps and came across a piece of code for references and pointers that I do not understand.

The code is `void (* fn) (int& a, int* b) = add;`. As far as I know it does not affect the program itself but would like to know what this code does.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add (int& a, int* b)
{
    cout << "Total: " << (a+ *b) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int num = 100, sum = 200;
    int rNum = num;
    int* ptr = &num;

    void (* fn) (int& a, int* b) = add;

    cout << "reference: " << rNum << endl;
    cout << "pointer: " << *ptr << endl;

    ptr = &sum;
    cout << "pointer now: " << *ptr << endl;
    add(rNum, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Heres](http://cdecl.org/) a very good website for declarations. It's having trouble with this one, though.

Comment: This instruction assigns the variable `fn`, a pointer to function, the value of a pointer to the function `add`. `fn` isn't used later and the assignment is essentially useless.

Comment: @awesomeyi Because references aren't in C, and you can't name the arguments in declarations there either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the spiral rule:

```
     +----------------------+
     |  +--+                |
     |  ^  |                |
void (* fn ) (int& a, int* b) = add;
^    |     |                |
|    +-----+                |
+---------------------------+
```

`fn` is a pointer to a function taking two arguments (an `int&` named `a` and a `int*` named `b`) and returning `void`. The function pointer is copy initialized with the free function `add`.

So where in your code you have:

```
add(rNum, ptr);
```

That could be equivalently replaced by:

```
fn(rNum, ptr);
```

Comment: There is no assignment here and, even if there were, it would be `add` assigned to `fn` and not the other way around.

Comment: Right, flipped the words in my head. Fixed.

Comment: Perhaps [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) is better than spiral rule since [it can't handle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16260417/183120) something as simple as `int *a[5][10]`?

Comment: @legends2k Both rules suck and everybody should just use typedefs :)

Comment: Haha, that's true, using `typedef`s would be much better. However, once we're into the business of decrypting such declarations, which do turn up in the wild frequently, RL rule is preferred since it handles cases even the spiral rule fails to :)

Answer (score 8):

`fn` is a pointer to a function taking, from left to right, an `int&`, and an `int*`, that does not return anything.

You are *assigning* the function `add` to `fn`.

You *could* call the function `add` through the pointer, using exactly the same syntax as you would if you were use `add`.

One use of this technique is in the modelling of *callback* functions. For example, `qsort` requires a callback function for the sorting predicate. Function pointers are more common in C than in C++ where there are other techniques such as function objects, templates, lambdas, and even `std::function`.

Answer (score 4):

If you read about [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) the declaration is easy to decipher:

You declare a variable `fn`, which is a pointer, to a function, taking some arguments and returning nothing.

Then you make this function-pointer `fn` point to the `add` function.

You can then use the function-pointer instead of calling `add` directly.

Answer (score 3):

`void (* fn) (int& a, int* b) = add;` declares a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) named `fn` that points that points to a function that has a signature of `void(int&,int*)`.  it then intilizes the pointer to the `add()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Such complicated declarations are easily read using the [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html), which works even when [the clockwise spiral rule fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error#comment28535671_16260417), which does even in case of something as simple as `int* a[][10]`.

```
void (* fn) (int& a, int* b);
```

Start with the identifier `fn` and go from right to left, with the parenthesis flipping the direction. So `fn` is a pointer to a function taking are reference to `int` and a pointer to `int` and the function's return type is `void`.

It's called reading [boustrophedonically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon) :) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859676/183120) for another example.

Comment: [Right-Left Rule from Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20210523053011/https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html) as original link is broken.