# Why is `int ( *array )[10] = malloc(...);` valid C code?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax, malloc

I recently came across the following:

```
int ( *array )[10] = malloc(...);
```

Based on my understanding of C's syntax and grammar, this looks like nonsense. It looks like an array is being created (and initialized) with the value of a dereferenced pointer as its identifier.

I understand the idea of pointers to arrays and assigning them blocks on the heap with malloc(), in general, at least. For instance, this makes sense:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof (int*) * 10);
```

...but, the first example looks like gibberish that shouldn't compile. Obviously, I'm missing something.

I feel like I saw whatever this is back when I was learning C, but Googling isn't helping to refresh my understanding. Searches with the terms "pointer", "dereferencing", and "initialization" obviously give results polluted with information on how one keeps track of dereferencing, etc. I'm hoping a human can help me.

Comment: Wasn't my example clear? :-( You could have told me and I would try to explain it further.

Comment: It looks weird, but `int (*foo)[10]` declares `foo` as a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s. Remove `()` and `int *foo[10]` declares foo as an array of 10 `pointers to int`s.

Comment: This question sounds almost the same like asking, why is `int[]` and `int[][]` (by the way I'm not saying that `int arr[][]` are the same as `(*arr)[]` ) allowed.

Comment: The link in this answer points to a guide on how to read C type declarations. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35549769/646887

Comment: @CircleSquared Please take a look [at this Demo](http://ideone.com/fUiQv1) and this [Demo](http://ideone.com/LN38l4) it will help

Comment: I believe [Freaky way of allocating two-dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794202/freaky-way-of-allocating-two-dimensional-array) best answers your question.

Comment: @KevinDTimm No. It is not. I asked that question, and it has to do with the workings of reallocate(). This has to do with the syntax of pointer declarations. This, however, does look like a duplicate to the questions Klas Lindbäck and Lundin linked.

Comment: @2501 It was turning into its proper within question of its own and I didn't want to harangue you until you until i got the new comprehensive explanation I needed.

Comment: @CircleSquared I support your actions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is perfectly legal - you are allocating a pointer to an array of ten integers.

A good way to complete `...` in your `malloc` is to use `sizeof(*array)` if you need only one array<sup>*</sup>:

```
int ( *array )[10] = malloc(sizeof(*array));
```

> For instance, this makes sense: `int *array = malloc(sizeof (int*) * 10);`

This is an array of `int`s. The first syntax lets you create an array of arrays of `int`s - for example

```
int ( *array )[10] = malloc(50*sizeof(*array));
```

gives you a 50×10 array.

<sup>*</sup> Here is a [good explanation of why `sizeof(*array)` is a good way of sizing your allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17258647/335858).

Comment: You may give a small note or possibly a link on why you used `sizeof *array`.

Comment: @sjsam Good point, thanks!

Comment: " `int ( *array )[10] = malloc(50*sizeof(*array));` gives you a 50×10 array. "

It sounds like you're saying that it would created a 2D array, but wouldn't that be a single array (sized 50x10)? And, wouldn't that force you to access the array with `array[x * y]` if you wanted to use in as a 2D array?

Comment: @CircleSquared Technically, this would give you a 1D array of 50 1D arrays, 10 `int`s each. C lets you treat this array as a 2D array. It wouldn't force you to access the array with a single indexer: `array[indexUpTo50][indexUpTo10]` will work fine. [Demo](http://ideone.com/hSS3sR).

Comment: Thanks so much! Wow, I clearly need to revisit the books on this.

Comment: @CircleSquared I am almost certain that this syntax is missing from the K&R book. The book explains allocation of jagged arrays at great length, but it does not talk about allocating arrays of fixed-size arrays at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
int ( *array )[10] = malloc(...);
```

declares `array` as a pointer to a 10-element array of `int`; the pointer is initialized with the result of the `malloc` call.  It's the same as writing

```
int (*array)[10] = NULL;
array = malloc( ... );
```

Remember that

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

will allocate enough storage to hold `N` instances of `T` and assign the resulting pointer value to `p`. This is true for *any type `T`*.

If we replace `T` with an array type like `R [10]`, we get

```
R (*p)[10] = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

The semantics are exactly the same, all that's changed is the type of `p`; we're allocating enough storage to hold `N` instances of `R [10]`.

> Based on my understanding of C's syntax and grammar, this looks like nonsense.

Then you need to revisit that understanding.  C declaration syntax is a *lot* more complex than most people think.  See section 6.7 of the [online C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

**EDIT**

Here's how the syntax breaks down:

```
int     (   *         array    )[     10     ]  = malloc( ... );
^       ^   ^           ^      ^^     ^      ^  ^ ^
|       |   |           |      ||     |      |  | |
|       | pointer     direct   ||     |      |  | assignment
|       |   |       declarator ||     |      |  | expression
|       |   |           |      ||     |      |  | |
|       |   +-----+-----+      ||     |      |  | |
|       |         |            ||     |      |  | |
|       |     declarator       ||     |      |  | |
|       |         |            ||     |      |  | |
|       +---------+------------+|     |      |  | |
|                 |             |     |      |  | |
|               direct          | assignment |  | |
|             declarator        | expression |  | |
|                 |             |     |      |  | |
|                 +-------------+-----+------+  | |
|                               |               | |
|                             direct            | |
|                           declarator          | |
type                            |               | |
specifier                   declarator          | initializer
|                               |               | |
|                               +---------------+-+
|                                               |
|                                          init-declarator
declaration                                     |
specifiers                              init-declarator-list
|                                               |
+----------------------+------------------------+
                       |
                   declaration
```

I'm omitting intermediate steps from `10` to `assignment-expression` and from `malloc(...)` to `initializer` because they'd just make the diagram harder to read.

Answer (score 5):

The address of an array and the address of its first element are equal each other.

So if you have an array as for example

```
int array[10];
```

then the values of the pointers `p` and `q`

```
int *p = array;
```

and

```
int ( *q )[10] = &array;
```

will be the same though the types of the pointers are different.

These values are equal to the addresses of the first elements of the arrays. In the first case the type of the element is `int` while in the second case the type of the element is `int[10]` But in the both cases it is the address of the allocated extent of memory that is not changed depending on how it is interpretated in C.

You can get the pointer `p` from the pointer `q` the following way

```
p = *q;
```

Take into account that function `malloc` returns a pointer to void that is of type `void *` that in C can be implicitly converted to a pointer of any other type.

Thus these statements

```
int ( *array )[10] = malloc( 10 * sizeof( int ) );
```

and

```
int *array = malloc( 10 * sizeof( int ) );
```

are valid in C.

On the other hand function free uses as its parameter again a pointer of type `void *`. And a pointer of other type can be implicitly converted to the type `void *`.