# What does int (*f[])(int*) represent?

Tags: c

This is one of the exam questions and the goal is to determine what the program will write. I am really confused about what `int (*f[])(int*) = {f1, f2, f2, f1 };` is. I taught that it may be an array whose elements are results of the functions in the brackets and those results are addresses that point on to an int.

Could you maybe explain it to me please?

And as well, what parameter does the function `f[i++]` get in

`for (i=0; i<2; a += fx(f[i++], a));`

**Problem:**

```
int f2(int *p) { return *p-- + 2; }

int f1(int *q) { return ++*q; }

int fx(int (*pf)(int*), int q) {
    int t = q;
    while ((t = pf(&q)) % 2) q+=2;
    return t;
}

#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a = 4, b = 3, *p = &b, i;
    int (*f[])(int*) = {f1, f2, f2, f1 };

    for (i=0; i<2; a += **fx(f[i++]**, a));
    printf("%d", a + *p);
}
```

Comment: indents! Indents! INDENTS!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Applying the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

```
int (*f[])(int*)
      ^                f is

int (*f[])(int*)
      ^^^              f is an array

int (*f[])(int*)
    ^^^^^^             f is an array of pointers

int (*f[])(int*)
    ^^^^^^^....^       f is an array of pointers to functions


int (*f[])(int*)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^       f is an array of pointers to functions
                       that accept a pointer to int

int (*f[])(int*)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       f is an array of pointers to functions
                       that accept a pointer to int and return a int value
```

Comment: Ow thank you so much!

Just another thing. Why isn't 
int (*f[])(int*) written as int (int*)(*f[])? I mean, it kinda makes more sense for me.
And can it be written in that way?

Comment: Hmmm .... C was designed such that *"declaration follows usage"*. You use functions with the syntax `obj = fx(parm1, parm2, ...);` and the way to declare pointers to functions follows that structure.

Comment: @pmg; [Spiral rule do not work for all cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16265389/2455888).

Comment: best way to explain things ever! :D

Answer (score 4):

It declares `f` as an array of pointers to function that returns `int` and take `int *` as an argument.

There is a precedence rule for understanding complex declarations which is discussed in the book [Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298):

> The Precedence Rule for Understanding C Declarations
>
> - A.  Declarations are read by starting with the name and then reading in precedence order.
> - B. The precedence, from high to low, is:
>
> > - B.1. parentheses grouping together parts of a declaration
> > - B.2. the postfix operators:
> >       parentheses `()` indicating a function, and
> >       square brackets `[]` indicating an array.
> > - B.3. the prefix operator:
> >       the asterisk denoting "pointer to".
>
> - C. If a `const` and/or `volatile` keyword is next to a type specifier (e.g. `int`, `long`, `etc`.) it applies to the type specifier. Otherwise the `const` and/or `volatile` keyword applies to the pointer asterisk on its immediate left.

Therefore, it goes like:

```
      f                          -- f (A)
     f[]                         -- is an array (B.1)
    *f[]                         -- of pointers to (B.3)
   (*f[])( )                     -- function (B.2)
 (*f[])( int * )                 -- that expects a pointer to an int as an argument
int (*f[])( int* )               -- and return an int
```

I would suggest to avoid spiral rule as it [fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265389/2455888) in some cases, for example in case of `int* a[10][15];`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take that apart with the help of the awesome [C gibberish to English website](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*f%5B%5D%29%28int*%29):

```
int (*f[])(int*)
```

> declare f as array of pointer to function (pointer to int) returning int

`f` is an array of function pointers.

hence, using the `{}` array initializer to store the functions in it is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the usual teaching method, I suggest you start from the *outside* in. Recognize the general structure of the declaration and proceed by refinement: replace the coarse-grained "blobs" that you see with more detailed ones. In other words, traverse the syntax from the root of the syntax tree to the leaves, rather than trying to pick out the right leaf and working bottom up.

The general structure of a declaration (that has a single declarator) is:

```
TYPE WHATEVER;
```

`WHATEVER` is being declared, related to `TYPE`.

Now note that `TYPE` is `int`, so `WHATEVER` is of type `int`. And `WHATEVER` has the general shape `(W1)(W2)`: two syntactic units in parentheses, whatever 1 and whatever 2:

```
int (W1)(W2);
```

Here, `W1` is what is being declared, and it is a function returning `int`, which takes a `W2` parameter list.  The latter actually denotes `int *`:

```
int (W1)(int *);
```

Thus `W1` is a function returning `int` which takes `int *`.  But `W1` is actually `*W3`, which makes `W3` a pointer to `W1`'s type.

```
int (*W3)(int *);
```

`W3` is a pointer to a function returning `int` which takes `int *`.

And `W3` is actually `f[]`, so `f` is an array of unspecified size of `W3`'s type:

```
int (*f[])(int *);
```

`f` is an array of unspecified size of pointers to function returning `int` which takes `int *`.

**Tip:** How do we know that `W1` isn't actually `W3[]` where `W3` is then `*f`?   This is because the type construction operator `[...]` is syntactically similar to the postfix array indexing operator `[...]` and the type constructing `*` is similar to the dereferencing unary operator `*`.  The unary operator has a *lower predecence* than the postfix operator. When we see `*X[]` we know it means `*(X[])` and not `(*X)[]`. The symbols `*X` do not form a syntactic unit in that phrase.  If we want the second meaning, we have to use the parentheses.

The syntax tree is:

```
                           declaration
                            |      |
               +------------+      +----------------+
               |                                    |
 specifier-qualifier list -- TYPE              declarator -- WHATEVER
               |                                |       |
              int                         +-----+       |
                                          |             |
                                     function -- W1    params -- W2
                                          |               |
                                       pointer -- W3    (int *)
                                          |
                                        array -- f
```

The helpful symbols like `W3` are just labels for the nodes as we traverse from root to leaves.  The name being declared in a `C` declaration is somewhere at the bottom of the tree, unlike in some other languages. As go deeper **into** the tree, we are actually emerging **out** of the type, so finally when we arrive at the bottom, we know the most important things: `f` is being declared, and overall it is an array of something.

Answer (score 0):

Following [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) we will see that `f` is an array of pointers to functions, where each function in the array is taking an `int*` argument and returning an `int`.

The initialization simply initializes this array with some function pointers.

Knowing what `f` is should help with the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int (*f[])(int*) = {f1, f2, f2, f1 };
```

is a declaration of an array of function pointers of type int( int * ) that is of functions that have return type `int` and one parameter of type `int *`.

As `f` is an array then `f[i++]`  is an element of the array that has one of the values f1, f2 and so on.

This function

```
int fx(int (*pf)(int*), int q);
```

has two parameters: a pointer to a function that has type int( int * ) and an object of type int.

So this expression

```
fx(f[i++], a)
```

is a call of the function that accespts as arguments one of the function pointers f1, f2 and so on and object `a`

Answer (score 0):

It essentially defines an array of function pointers. The following:

```
int (*f[])(int*) = {f1, f2, f2, f1};
```

combines definition with array initializer. That is why you can omit size of an array, since it is deduced from initializer. The type of each element is:

```
int (*)(int*)
```

which is function pointer for function that takes one argument of type `int *` and returns `int`.

The `for` loop's body consist of empty statement. You may rewrite it for better clarity as:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 2; a += fx(f[i++], a))
    ;
```

There are two iterations for `i = 0` and `i = 1`. Each time `a` is incremented by result of function call:

```
fx(f[i++], a)
```

First argument is an address of function, that is stored in `f` array. It is `f[0]` and `f[1]` respectively (i.e. `f1` and `f2`). You might use equivalent form:

```
fx(&f[i++], a)
```

but there would be no real difference (it is just matter of preference).

If it looks too strange or complex for you, then you might rewrite `for` loop as:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 2; a += fx(f[i], a), i++)
    ;
```

as well as:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
    a += fx(f[i], a);
```