# What does i = * ( long * ) &y; do?

Tags: c

I saw following code [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code).

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the heck? 
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
//  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

    return y;
}
```

I don't understand following line.

```
i  = * ( long * ) &y;
```

Generally, we use `*` and `&` with pointer, but here both used with variable. So, what does it do here?

Comment: Crazy way to convert a float to a long?

Comment: isn't that the fast square root algorithm. yes it is.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I didn't think about getting the bits for the exp quickly that way, pretty neat.

Comment: it violently memcpys the float to long to do some magic mask & shifting. I linked to a SO question which somehow explains

Comment: `float x2, y;...
    i  = * ( long * ) &y; ` is undefined behavior.  Use a `union`.

Comment: @chux I think this code predates the strict-aliasing rule.

Comment: @DanielH and so that old code is likely still good with old C compilers running on old platforms.  Likely neither of those apply for OP.

Comment: See also the explanation of "undefined behavior" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: See this post on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/3xyo0t/til_quake_iii_arena_needing_to_calculate_x12/

Comment: Back in the day, this is what we did.

Comment: @Daniel H, Sounds backwards. Memory alignment restrictions is not a new thing.

Comment: @ikegami I think the strict aliasing rule was implemented in C99. This algorithm is newer than I thought, and also from 1999.

Comment: @chux I doubt the OP is trying to use this code, just understand it. It doesn’t even work on a lot of modern systems, where `long` is 64-bits, whether or not you have strict aliasing turned off.

Comment: @Daniel H, But memory alignment issues predate C99 by a lot, and that code can fail because of memory alignment issues. I don't know if that counts as undefined behaviour, but it might as well count since the result is the same.

Comment: @ikegami Bad memory alignment is UB, but I think `float`s usually have 4-byte alignment and the stack is usually more aligned than that anyway so it doesn’t matter.

Comment: The code "works" be cause of UB (a lot of UB).  It is that the author's use resulted in a nice UB.

Comment: @chux Even if the original code used C99 and the type punning was UB, it’s the only UB I see; that’s not “a lot of UB”. It depends on the sizes, alignments, and representations of `float` and `long`, which are implementation-defined. It’s not portable, but that isn’t a synonym for undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielH I agree with your "it’s the only UB I see".  Yet we are venturing OT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line is taking a `float`, looking at the memory holding that `float`, reinterpreting that memory as memory holding a `long`, and getting that `long`. Basically, it's reinterpreting the bit-pattern of a floating point number as that of an integer, in order to mess around with its bits.

Unfortunately, that code is also *wrong*. You are not allowed to dereference that casted pointer, for reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). In C, the one-and-only way of reinterpreting a bit pattern is through `memcpy`. (Depending on C variant and implementation, going through a union *may* be acceptable as well.)

Comment: Can you give a quick explanation on the major difference between a memcopy and doing the cast straight away (not through addressing)?

Comment: @kabanus What do you mean by "doing the cast straight away"?

Comment: I mean `i=(long)y`

Comment: @kabanus The difference is that in `(long)y`, a number is being converted. In the OP's case, a *memory address* is being converted. You're telling the compiler "you know that memory address? Pretend that the data there is an integer, not a float". Of course it isn't really, so the value you get out will be as much about how floating point numbers are represented as it is about what the number in question actually *was*.

Comment: Thanks, and I think that's worth to put in the answer. NM, I see this was closed :)

Comment: I’m pretty sure the C standard still allows unions for type punning; I think it’s only C++ that prohibits them.

Comment: @DanielH C99 does, but C89 was cagey about it.

Answer (score 2):

First, a disclaimer: This is technically undefined behavior because it violates the [strict aliasing rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing), but most compilers will do the below, and I don’t know what the standards situation was when this was first written.

When you look at the expression, there are four main parts:(

1. `y` is the float variable we want to convert. Simple enough.
2. `&` is the usual address-of operator, so `&y` is a pointer to `y`.
3. `(long *)` is a cast to a pointer to long, so `(long *) &y` is a pointer-to-long pointing to the same location in memory as `y` is at. There is no real `long` there, just a `float`, but if both `float` and `long` are 32 bits (like the code assumes), this will give you a pointer to a `long` with the same bit pattern as a `float`.
4. Finally, `*` dereferences the pointer. Thus, the full expression, `* ( long * ) &y;`, gives you a `long` with same bit pattern as `y`.

Usually, a `long` with the same bit pattern as a `float` would be useless, because they store numbers in completely different ways. However, it’s easier to do bit manipulation to a `long`, and the program later converts it back to a `float.

Answer (score 0):

It means the address of `y` (making it a pointer) cast to a `long` pointer, dereferenced and assigned to `i`.

Comment: [There isn't really a spiral rule.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error)  There also isn't a spiral in this particular case.

Comment: To clarify @OliverCharlesworth’s comment, the spiral rule is a simplification of the actual C++ type-parsing rules. Since it’s a simplification, there are a lot of cases where the spiral rule gives the wrong answer. In any case, it’s only for parsing types, not expressions.