# Const twice in one method parameter?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and trying to understand some code I'm looking at:

`bool ClassName::ClassMethod(const STRUCT_THING* const parameterName) {}`

What is the purpose of the second "const" in the argument?  How does it differ from just `const STRUCT_THING* parameterName`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means it is a `const` pointer to a `const` variable.

See the following examples:

```
int x = 5;                // non-const int
int* y = &x;              // non-const pointer to non-const int

int const a = 3;          // const int
int* const b = &a;        // const pointer to non-const int
int const* const c = &a;  // const pointer to const int
```

So you can see that two things have the potential to be mutable, the variable and the pointer. Either of these two can be `const`.

A `const` variable works just as you'd imagine:

```
int foo = 10;
foo += 5;     // Okay!

int const bar = 5;
bar += 3;     // Not okay! Should result in a compiler warning (at least)
```

A `const` pointer works the same way:

```
int foo = 10;
int bar = 5;

int* a = &foo;
a = &bar;  // Okay!

int* const b = &foo;
b = &bar;  // Not okay! Should also result in a compiler warning.
```

Comment: What is the rule for determining what the `const` is referring to? Like, is it just whatever is to the left of the `const`?

Comment: @BWG See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526152/easy-rule-to-read-complicated-const-declarations). Basically you read from right to left, with a couple exceptions.

Comment: @Cyber that seems awfully unintuitive since in English, descriptors precede the target.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It might be important to note that the last `const` does not affect the function signature. That is, `void foo(int const * const)` and `void foo(int const *)` are two *declarations* for the same function. It does however affect the compiler checks in the definition of the function where it will ensure that the function does not attempt to reset the pointer to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Read it from right to letf:

parameterNam is constant pointer of type STRUCT_THING which happened to be const.

Basically you can't change it, and you can't change what it points to.

Comment: Gotchya.  So if I had just one or the other "const"s, then either the pointer could be made to point to something else or the unchangable pointer would be pointing to something mutable?

Answer (score 0):

You using a `const` pointer to a `const` variable, which are two different things.

The difference is one is a `const` pointer, which is essentially pointing to the `const` variable.