# Whats the difference between const int const& and const int& in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In c++ i can write `const int const*` for a constant pointer to an constant int.
I can also write `const int&` for a const reference. So is `const int const&` a reference to a const int?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `In c++ i can write const int const* for a constant pointer to an int.` No, thats a duplicate const for the int and none for the pointer.

Comment: Please separate your code from the text, it is not clear what types you try to create here

Comment: The difference is that you can write `const int &` but you can't write `const int const &`.

Comment: @tkausl yes i meant const int const* for const int

Comment: @Francois you can it wont create an error!

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx Most compilers will give you an error. Visual Studio gives you a warning, though it's known to allow a lot of things it shouldn't. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy rule to read complicated const declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526152/easy-rule-to-read-complicated-const-declarations)

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx Keep in mind that it's not because a compiler doesn't complain that code is valid or correct. The compiler is *not* required to identify every error in your code.

Comment: Yeah :/ im using VC++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is const int const& a reference to a const int?

No, that's a [compilation error](https://ideone.com/sxMeqV).

Try compiling something like :

```
int z = 0;
const int const& a= z;
```

And you'll see the compiler will yell at you.

You can't duplicate `const` for the same type. Your premise that `const int const*` is a constant pointer to a constant `int` is wrong too.

Comment: It seems that OP's compiler does not actually yell at them for that (though I'm pretty sure you're right, and it should).

Comment: At Vs2017 and C++ 17 i didnt get an error :/ But ty

Comment: Then instead of your compiler yelling at you, you should yell at your compiler.

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx If you disable language extensions with `/Za` you will get an error ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/Q6iFr7)) though you should still be seeing a warning without it.

Comment: thats a useful tip ty!

Answer (score 8):

`const int const*` is not a constant pointer to a constant `int`.  To get that you need

```
const int * const.
```

In your case you apply both `const` to the `int` so you have a mutable pointer to a constant `int`.

The same thing happen to `const int const&`.  To make a constant reference  to a constant `int` you would need

```
const int & const
```

but that is illegal.

Do note that in both `const int const*` and `const int const&` it's not actually legal to apply `const` twice like that.

Comment: ty too for ur answer!

Answer (score 3):

It is always a good idea to read it backwards as suggested by the [Clockwise/Spiral](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) rule if you get stuck in understanding such declarations.

```
int const *    // pointer to const int
int * const    // const pointer to int
int const * const   // const pointer to const int
int * const * p3;   // pointer to const pointer to int
const int * const * p4;       // pointer to const pointer to const int
```