# Golang, Go : why pointer use star operator instead of &

Tags: c, pointers, go

The [code](http://play.golang.org/p/-a6zv4Q3Xl):

```
type ByteSlice []byte

func (p *ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) {
  slice := *p
  slice = append(slice, data...)
  *p = slice
}

func main() {
  x := ByteSlice{1, 2, 3}
  y := []byte{4, 5}
  x.Append(y)
  fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Ok, I understand why and how pointer works, but I've always wondered why we use `*` operator to pass pointer to function.

- `*ptr` is to deference the ptr and return the value saved in the pointer ptr.
- `&var` returns the address of the variable var.

Why we do not use `&ByteSlice` to pass pointer to function?

I am confused. Isn't this function passing pointer?

According to Go spec (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types)

> PointerType = "*" BaseType .
>
> BaseType = Type .

This also confuses me. Why we use star(`*`) operator both to get the pointer of variable and dereference pointer? Looks like we don't use `&` for this case both in C and Go...

Comment: The use of `*` instead of `&` in pointer declarations stems for the C principle that [declaration syntax follows usage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3707096/166749).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The * in `func (p *ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) {` is simply declaring that `p` is of type `*ByteSlice`.

The passing of a pointer takes place here:

```
x.Append(y)
```

As the [Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) says (my emphasis):

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. *If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m():*

In your case, `x.Append(y)` is a shorthand for `(&x).Append(y)`. There you have your &-sign.

Comment: Thanks, I think my question is more C syntax. I was confused by * which also can be used to dereference pointer. * can do both? One to dereference pointer, and the other to get the pointer of invoked variable?

Comment: Yes. * is used in declaration to say that `*ByteSlice` is a pointer to a ByteSlice. And it is also used for dereference a pointer, (*p). However, * is never used to retrieve a pointer; & will be used for that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'retrieve' a pointer? You mean to retrieve a pointer of variable, we only use & operator? like &num?

Comment: I see! "& will be used for that"  Good to know! Everything is clear now!

Comment: Exactly :) . Sorry, I added that last sentence in an edit. Glad to help!