# Is C++ operator "*" left-associative or right-associative?

Tags: c++, associative

I've got a test program to try this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int* p, q;
    p = &i;
    //q = &i;//q is not pointer
    int* buf[20];//type of element is int*
    return 0;
}
```

(1) I found `q` is not pointer, so seems `int *p` the asterisk is right-associative.

(2) But for `int* buf[20]`, I found `buf` an array of 20 elements, each typed with `int*`. So in line 5, seems the asterisk is left-associative.

So what's the exact rule of how `*` is associated with other parts of an expression, left-associative or right-associative, or apply to other rules?

Comment: `p` and `q` are different variables, they might be different types. But it's impossible to declare an array with the 1st element is a pointer, but the 2nd element is not.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into this.  The first line declares two separate items, the other line declares a single item (an array).

Comment: Related: [Spiral rule and 'declaration follows usage' for parsing C and C++ declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-and-c-declarations)

Comment: in `int p, *q, r[3], *s[3], (*t)[3];` -- `p` is `int`, `q` is pointer to `int`, `r` is array of `int`, `s` is array of pointer to `int`, and `t` is pointer to array of `int`

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any `operator*`.

Comment: The asterisk in the type is not a binary operator; it has no associativity. Associativity only matters in expressions with two or more binary operators. The multiplication operator `*` is left-associative, which means that `a * b * c` is `(a * b) * c`, not `a * (b * c)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A declaration consists of a sequence of specifiers followed by a sequence of declarators. Each declarator declares one name. Each specifier applies to each declarator *independently.* Hence in

```
int* p, q;
```

the specifier `int` applies to both `p` and `q`. However, `*` is not a specifier, and is instead part of the declarator `*p`, so it only applies to `p`.

`*` binds to the entity on its right, but it has lower precedence than `[]` and `()`. This precedence rule is the same as that for expressions. `&` and `&&` (C++ only) have the same precedence as `*`. In

```
int* buf[20];
```

there is one specifier, `int`, and one declarator, `*buf[20]`, and the `[20]` binds more tightly, so it's an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array, and the base type is `int`, so it's an array of pointers to `int`.

The binding can be altered by parentheses:

```
int* buf[20]; // array of pointers
int (*buf)[20]; // pointer to array
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working right

```
int* p, q;
```

Since it doest matter it was int* p or int *p, the issue here is that q is after the comma which will need another pointer * if you want it to be a pointer too.

This line:

```
int* buf[20];//type of element is int*
```

Also does what is supposed to do, declare array of int pointers, which is the same as int *buf[20]