# Meaning of multi-dimensional array declaration in C++

Tags: c++

I have problems to understand following multi-dimensional array declaration in C++.

```
static const byte LAYER_SIZE = 3;
static const byte ROWS = 5;
static const byte COLS = 10;

static const byte (*colorMapping[LAYER_SIZE]) [ROWS][COLS];
```

What does this declaration do?

Especially the part

```
(*colorMapping[LAYER_SIZE])
```

is confusing for me - what is the meaning of this and what does it in combination with [ROWS][COLS]?

Comment: Colour mapping seems to be an array of pointers of size LAYER_SIZE and each of these pointers point to a 2D Array (Matrix) of size ROWS COLS, where the values are of size byte.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-and-c-declarations

Comment: Replacing the constants, and using a standard type instead of `byte`, [this](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+char+(*colorMapping[3])+[5][10]%3B) says "declare colorMapping as array 3 of pointer to array 5 of array 10 of const char"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to understand is to compare examples of declarations with and without brackets. Just like in an expression brackets are used to affect the *precedence* of various parts of the declaration.

For instance, starting simple,

```
int* array[10];
```

is an array of ten pointers. But what if you want a pointer to an array instead of an array of pointers? That would be

```
int (*ptr)[10];
```

The brackets mean that `ptr` is *firstly* a pointer, and it's only when that pointer is dereferenced that you get to the array.

So this example

```
int* (array[10]);
```

is the same as the first example. The superfluous brackets make clear that `array` is firstly an array and that only when you get to the elements of the array that you have a pointer. What the above examples are saying is that in a declaration (just like in an expression) `[]` has higher precedence than `*` and if you want it the other way round you have to use brackets.

So going to the original example

```
static const byte (*colorMapping[LAYER_SIZE]) [ROWS][COLS];
```

Looking inside the brackets first we have an array of pointers (just like my first example above). Then looking outside the brackets we see that each pointer points to a two dimensional array.

If we missed out the brackets

```
static const byte *colorMapping[LAYER_SIZE][ROWS][COLS];
```

then we'd have a three dimensional array of pointers.

Hopefully that's clear.

Comment: Thank your for your comprehensive answer. So this means: There is a constant array defined having LAYER_SIZE which contains pointers to 2-dimensional arrays of dimension [ROW][COL] where each element (of the matrix) holds a byte?

Comment: @asterix That's right. What are constant are the bytes. The pointers are not constant (you would need `static const byte (*const colorMapping[LAYER_SIZE])[ROWS][COLS];` for that).

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies the matter for me! C/C++ syntax is really hard to understand sometimes!