# How do I read this complex declaration in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [what's the meaning of this piece of code? void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcin)

I have a complex declaration which have been taken from the "signal.h" header file, and below is the declaration.

```
  void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

Now, how do I parse it? As

> signal is function taking two arguments ‘sig’ of int type and ‘func’, which is a pointer to a function taking int as an argument and returns void type; it returns a pointer to the function taking int as argument and returning void.

Is it OK or signal is a pointer to function?

Comment: But this is where i got confused from http://www.joyofprogramming.com/Docs_ColumnArticles/36-JoP-Dec-09.pdf

Comment: `typedef int foo(void)`: foo is a pointer to function, but you can shortcut it and say it is a function, because you can do `foo x; x();`

Comment: @Benoit can you please add it as your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure on what basis my question got closed ,what I have asked is different from what's being asked before.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that `[]` and `()` bind before `*`, so `*a[]` is an array of pointers, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function:

```
       signal                                     -- signal
       signal(                          )         -- is a function
       signal(    sig,                  )         -- with a parameter named sig
       signal(int sig,                  )         --   of type int
       signal(int sig,        func      )         -- and a parameter named func
       signal(int sig,      (*func)     )         --   which is a pointer
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(   ))         --   to a function
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(int))         --     taking an int parameter
       signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))         --     and returning void
      *signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))         -- returning a pointer
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(   )   -- to a function
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)   --   taking an int parameter
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);  --   and returning void
```

`signal` associates a signal handler function `func` with a signal `sig`, and returns the pointer to the old signal handler function:

```
void new_interrupt_handler(int sig)
{
  ... // do something interesting with interrupt signal
}

int main(void)
{
  void (*old_interrupt_handler)(int);
  ...
  /**
   * Set up our new interrupt handler
   */
  old_interrupt_handler = signal(SIGINT, new_interrupt_handler);
  ...
  /**
   * Restore original interrupt handler
   */
  signal(SIGINT, old_interrupt_handler);
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice, step by step explanation.

Comment: Thanks @John for your  thoughts but some users here opposing it and saying signal is pointer to function .

Comment: @Amit - In Aaron's case, the string he fed to `cdecl` is not what you wrote in your question.

Comment: +1 One of the reasons why you use typedef for function pointers: it's easier on the brain. :)

Comment: @netcoder: It can certainly make declarations like this easier to read, but I like knowing what the function signature looks like without having to search for the typedef.  `sighandler func;` doesn't tell me how to *use* `func`, whereas `void (*func)(int);` does.

Comment: +1 For I wish your answer could be posted to the original question posted above for which this one is a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Using [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/), you get

> declare signal as function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void

for the input

```
void (*signal(int, void(*)(int)))(int)
```

This means `signal` is a function. The result of of calling `signal` is pointer to a function `void f(int)`.

Explanation: The `signal()` call installs a *new* signal handler and returns the *old* signal handler (so you can restore it later if you want to).

Comment: But in my context its different ,is n't it?

Comment: @Aaron - you didn't enter the same declaration as the OP.

Comment: @JohnBode: You're right. Fixed.

Comment: +1 for linking to [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 2):

```
void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);  

       signal(                  )         // signal is a function
              int, void (*)(int)          // the parameter types of the function:
                                          //    an int and a function pointer (take int, return void)
void (*                          )(int);  // the return type of the function:
                                          //    a function pointer (take int, return void)
```

// Edit referring to John's answer.

Comment: Now how signal is pointer to function ?

Comment: it tells signal is function returning pointer.

Comment: Its really confusing now ,most of the answer says its function returning pointer and you are saying different.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, `()` binds before `*`, so `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, *not* a pointer to a function.  The form of the declaration for `signal` includes `*signal(...)`, so `signal` is definitely a function returning a pointer.

Comment: much less pain for the brain that a complete grammatically correct English sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

`signal` is a function which takes two parameters and returns a pointer to a function which takes an `int` as the parameter and returns `void`.

The two parameters that `signal` takes are an `int` and a pointer to a function which takes `int` as a parameter and returns `void`.

And yes, you got the description and the overall idea right.

Answer (score 1):

No that's right. signal takes 2 arguments, an int and a pointer to a function  and returns a pointer to a function (with the same signature as the `func` argument.)

It's similar to the (imo) more readable:

```
typedef void (*sig_func)(int);
sig_func signal(int sig, sig_func func);
```

Comment: GNU calls it `sighandler_t`, libc4 and libc5 call it `SignalHandler` and glibc calls it `sig_t`, BTW. ;)

Comment: This is how you should write the code. If you aren't using typedef when declaring something so obscure as "a function pointer to a function taking function pointers as parameter", then you are evil and possibly quite daft.