# How do I read this complex C declaration?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am new to C and am having a problem reading this matrix declaration in a function.

`void foo(int (*array)[][3], int row, int col)`

and in the function how do I access an array element - say to print it's value.

Comment: It is an invalid syntax. Perhaps there is some context to it?

Comment: This could be useful

http://codinghighway.com/2013/12/29/the-absolute-definitive-guide-to-decipher-c-declarations/

Comment: This is probably an argument list of a function; in that case the function takes three arguments: a pointer to an array of arrays of 3 ints and two other ints. You can learn how to parse such declarations here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read this complex declaration in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500848/how-do-i-read-this-complex-declaration-in-c)

Comment: @szczurcio Yes It is part of the function. I made the change in the question

Comment: @cad It is part of a function declaration - made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int (*array)[][3]
```

declares `array` to be a pointer to a 2D array whose second dimension is `3`. Example usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int (*array)[][3], int row, int col)
{
   printf("%d\n", (*array)[row][col]);
}

int main()
{
   int array[10][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
   foo(&array, 2, 2);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9
```

Answer (score 1):

`(*array)[][3]` is a pointer to 2D array.it can point to an `int` array of variable rows and 3 columns.Here is an example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[3][3] =
    {
        {0,0,0},
        {1,0,0},
        {1,1,0},
    };
    int (*array)[3][3],row,col;
    array = &arr;
    printf("arr[1][0] : %d\n",(*array)[1][0]);
}
```