# Understanding some crazy C/C++ declarations

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to understand complicated function declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-to-understand-complicated-function-declarations)

Consider:

```
char (*(*x())[5])()
```

How do I dissect this expression?

I think it is a function which return an array of size 5, whose members are pointers to function which receive no input and return a char.

Am I right?

Comment: Check out http://cdecl.org/ for non-trivial declarations.

Comment: declare x as function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to function returning char - http://cdecl.org/

Comment: No it's a function that returns a pointer to an array of five pointers to functions taking (C: unspecified parameters | C++: no parameters) and returning a char. Functions are not allowed to return arrays in C or C++. Searching for duplicate...

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/

Comment: @hmjd: actually i know cdecl.org, but i want to know the theory to dissect this kind of expre.

Comment: @Jichao - Why? You are never going to need it (except when answering  questions here). If you use it in a real program, it is never going to pass a code review.

Comment: @BoPersson: I saw this expression, so I want to know how, and maybe i'll implement a c or c++ compiler in future, so i am glad to know every details of these two languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Search for "Right-left rule"

In your case, it should be:

```
         x          : x is a
         x()        : function
        *x()        : returning pointer to
       (*x())[5]    : a 5-element array of 
      *(*x())[5]    : pointer to
     (*(*x())[5])() : function
char (*(*x())[5])() : returning char
```

Comment: Not a 5-element array but an array with more than 5 elements.  It has at least 6.

Comment: @user1717828 I am curious on what do you mean by that.  The declaration is `[5]` which precisely means `array with 5 elements`.  Of course you can access beyond the 5th element but that's not what the declaration is telling you.

Comment: Well, now I'm just going to leave up my original comment so anyone else prone to fall in the same trap doesn't repeat my mistake.  I thought it was accessing the [5] (sixth) member of an array.  #noobmistakes

Answer (score 12):

I have been seeing a lot of weird declarations on Stack Overflow these days.

When I'm lazy, I use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/):

> "declare x as function returning pointer to array 5 of pointer to function returning char"

When not, there is the [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). **<- It is *AWESOME***