# How to read this variable declaration?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

```
int (*(*q)(int (*)()))();
```

Ok, I start with: q is a pointer to a function, which takes... Not sure what should follow next, but perhaps it's ...a pointer to function, which takes nothing and returns int, and returns pointer to a function, which takes nothing and returns int.

Comment: BTW you got it right. For the first try. Congrats!

Comment: It also says, "if you need to pass this code to anyone, pass it to Tony", because being hurt is a lot better than being skinned alive and then killed :-)

Comment: +1 for answering your own question on such a nightmare.

Comment: Its good answer: [Complex C declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111526/complex-c-declaration/15112210#15112210) , will help you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the lefmost identifier, then work your way out remembering that `*a[]` is an array of pointer, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function. Remember that in a prototype you only need to provide the type of the parameter; `int f( int );` declares `f` as a function that takes a single `int` parameter; `int f( int * );` declares `f` as a function that takes a single `int` pointer as a parameter.  Similarly, `int f( int (*)[N] );` declares `f` as a function that takes a pointer to an array as a parameter.  Apply these rules recursively to any parameters in the function.

Thus:

```
        q                  -- q
       *q                  -- is a pointer to
      (*q)(         )      --   a function
      (*q)(     *   )      --     that takes a pointer to
      (*q)(    (*)())      --       a function
      (*q)(int (*)())      --       returning int
     *(*q)(int (*)())      --   returning a pointer to
    (*(*q)(int (*)()))()   --       a function  
int (*(*q)(int (*)()))();  --       returning int
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that `q` itself is a function pointer that returns **and** takes a function pointer. [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.org/) says:

> declare q as pointer to function (pointer to function returning int) returning pointer to function returning int

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

q is a pointer point to a function passing  an pointer to a function (passing nothing returning int) returning a pointer to a function (passing nothing returning int).

See here. 
http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 1):

According to Precedence and associativity of Operators in the C Programming language.
You can understand it in the following steps:

```
int (*(*q)(int (*)()))();

q->*->(int (*)())->*->()->int
   1      2        3   4   5
```

1:q is a pointer

2:q is a function pointer, the function it points to has a parameter int (*)(), which is also a function pointer, points to a function has no parameters and return type is int.

3:q is a function pointer, the function it pointers to has parameter int (*)(), which is also a function pointer, points to a function has no parameters and return type is int. And
the function which q points to has a return type : pointer.

4:q is a function pointer, the function it pointers to has parameter int (*)(), which is also a function pointer, points to a function has no parameters and return type is int. And
the function which q points to has a return type : pointer(this pointer also points to a function which has no parameter).

5:q is a function pointer, the function it pointers to has parameter int (*)(), which is also a function pointer, points to a function has no parameters and return type is int. And
the function which q points to has a return type : pointer(this pointer also points to a function which has no parameter and the function's return type is int).