# How to read so many stars and parentheses in a templated function-pointer declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, declaration

From [Introduction to the C++11 feature: trailing return types](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_trailing_return_types?lang=en)

The article claims

```
template <class T> class tmp {
public:
    int i;
};

auto foo()->auto(*)()->tmp<int>(*)(){
    return 0;
}
```

is  equivalent to

```
template <class T> class tmp{
public:
    int i;
};

tmp<int> (*(*foo())())() {
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the complex function in the second code example. Where should I look at in the beginning? I guess is `foo`. But the stat right next to `foo` is going to define `foo` as a pointer...
Based on the first code example, I will convert the piece as

```
tmp<int> (*)() (*)() foo(){ return 0;}
```

So foo is a function, which returns 0, but the return type is tricky: its return type is functional pointer whose return type is again a function pointer whose return type is `tmp<int>`.

Comment: you are making a function pointer so you have to define everything in a function and * are for pointers and dereferencing of pointers.

Comment: For a start, code gets easier to read if you ident it properly ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex C declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111526/complex-c-declaration) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893013/complex-declarations or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448849/how-do-i-understand-complicated-function-declarations or etc.

Comment: "I don't understand the complex function in the second code example." that is exactly the point; the complex function declaration is unreadable (barring specific training to read it).  Hence use the alternative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In complement with @Vittorio answer, there is the [Clockwise Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to help us decypher complex types:

Starting with the unknown element, move in a spiral/clockwise direction; when encountering the following elements replace them with the corresponding English statements:

- `[X]` or `[]`

  > Array `X` size of... or Array undefined size of...
- `(type1, type2)`

  > Function passing type1 and type2 returning...
- `*`

  > pointer(s) to...

Keep doing this in a spiral/clockwise direction until all tokens have been covered. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first!

---

Here:

```
           +-----------+
           | +------+  |
           | | >-v  |  |
temp<int> (*(*foo())())()
        |  | ^---+  |  |
        |  ^--------+  |
        +--------------+
```

`foo` is a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a `temp<int>`.

---

And now, @UKmonkey just renamed this rule *The C++ Guru Snail Rule* or CGSR for short:

```
 / /
 L_L_
/    \
|00  |       _______
|_/  |      /  ___  \
|    |     /  /   \  \
|    |_____\  \_  /  /
 \          \____/  /_____
  \ _______________/______\.............................
```

Comment: Darn, if only ASCII art would compile...

Answer (score 24):

> Where should I look at in the beginning?

Honestly, you should just look at https://cdecl.org/, which describes `int (*(*foo())())();` as:

> declare foo as function returning pointer to function returning pointer to function returning int

And then realize that this is C++11, and we have a really nice syntax for declaring function pointer aliases:

```
using A = int(*)(); // pointer to function returning int
using B = A(*)();  // pointer to function returning pointer to function returning int

B foo(); // function returning pointer to function returning pointer to function returning int
```

There's really no reason to write declarations like that today.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can do that with `typedef` as well, though I don't know for sure. I'm also fairly sure it works in C++, too.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The point is having a *nice* syntax. `typedef int(*A)();` is not a nice syntax.

Comment: True, but you don't have that in C, which I just realized I accidentally called C++. Whoops.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yeah, that's why they call it C++. It's one better :-)

Comment: and *significantly* more than one page longer

Answer (score 5):

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is an useful online tool to demystify complicated C declarations.

Inserting `int (*(*foo())())()` returns:

> declare foo as function returning pointer to function returning pointer to function returning int

I've replaced `tmp<int>` with `int` as the tool does not support templates.

Answer (score 5):

Correctly formatting the code may help you comprehend:

```
template <class T>
class tmp {
    public:
    int i;
};

auto foo() -> auto(*)() -> tmp<int>(*)() {
    return 0;
}
```

```
template <class T>
class tmp{
    public:
    int i;
};

tmp<int> (*
    ( *foo() )()
    )() {
    return 0;
}
```

The `template class` part remains the same so I'm not going to elaborate on it. Let's see the function `foo`.

In the first code, the return value of `foo()` is `auto(*)() -> tmp<int>(*)()`, which is a pointer to a function returning another pointer, which points to a function returning `tmp<int>`.

As you can always define a function pointer like:

```
base_type_t (*pointer_name)(parameter_list);
```

Recursing the `pointer_name` with a function (i.e. `func_name()`) can declare a function whose return value is such a pointer:

```
base_type_t (*func_name())(parameter_list);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So now `(*func_name())(parameter_list)` can serve another function. Let's put it back into the function pointer definition syntax:

```
base_type_t (*(*func_name())(parameter_list))(parameter_list);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Clear the parameter list (they're empty) and replace the identifiers with the correct types gives:

```
base_type_t (*(*func_name())(parameter_list))(parameter_list);
tmp<int>    (*(*   foo   ())( /* Empty */  ))( /* Empty */  );

// Turns to
tmp<int> (*(*foo())())();
```

As others have already suggested, https://cdecl.org/ is a good code analyzer, though it may give you another sentence which is not quite easy to understand.