# array of 2 dimensions, one being known and the other unknown

Tags: c++, arrays, types

I need to efficiently allocate an array of two dimensions, one being known (5) and the other being unknown.

My aim is to have a continuous block of memory named block that stores my data in the following way :
block[0,0] block[0,1] block[0,2] block[0,3] block[0,4] block[1,0] ...]

The following code compiles (in C++) :

```
unsigned int size2=200;
auto block = new float[size2][5];
```

Is it correct ?
What is the type of the variable block ?
I have tried :

```
float[5]* block = new float[size2][5];
float[5] block[] = new float[size2][5];
float block[][5] = new float[size2][5];
float block*[5] = new float[size2][5];
```

All of them leads to an error.
I am running out of imagination...

Comment: How about creating array of pointers each points to a dynamic Array?

Comment: it allocates additional memory and will fragment allocated memory

Comment: What not use vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int size2=200;
auto block = new float[size2][5];
```

> Is it correct?

Yes it is correct.

> What is the type of the variable block?

Using `auto` here is the best you can do. But for learning purpose, the type of `block` is `float(*)[5]`. To define a variable with that type, you must use the following syntax:

```
unsigned int size2=200;
float(*block)[5] = new float[size2][5];
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4iJMA5

---

*"How can I read such a thing as `float(*block)[5]`?"* you might ask. It's simple, use the [C++ Guru Snail Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47835838/5470596).

Comment: You can do something similar defining a `typedef` allowing a somewhat more natural *pointer to array* allocation, e.g. `typedef float row_t[5]; ... row_t *block = new row_t[200];` (whether that is more clear or not is arguable)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> unsigned int size2=200;
> auto block = new float[size2][5];
> ```
>
> Is it correct ?

Yes, although a bare owning pointer is a bad idea. It's better to use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.

> What is the type of the variable block ?

It is `float (*)[5]` i.e. pointer to an array of 5 float.

---

As I mentioned, I recommend using `std::vector` instead to avoid pitfalls with memory management:

```
std::vector<std::array<float, 5>> block(size2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit old-school, but the simplest is really

```
new float[size2 * 5];
```

and access it with

```
my_array[y * 5 + x]
```

You can even add an inline helper function

```
int at(int x, int y) { return y * 5 + x;}
```

...

```
my_array[at(x,y)]
```

And ideally combine with a std::vector instead of a dynamic array.

Comment: I don't see how this is better than the questioner's own version tbh. Using this is more complicated.