# How to read this prototype?

Tags: c, prototype, function-pointers, declaration

Help me understand the following prototype. What is the last `(int)` doing?

```
void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int);
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1591492/1383051). It answers your question in great detail!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C: Examples, hints and tips, please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple)

Comment: @JimBalter, Not too sure it's a duplicate. That question aims at understanding function pointer `typedef`s. This question aims at understanding function pointer declarations. That question's answer just answers both questions. I can understand, however, if people close this question as an answer already exists.

Comment: See also: [What's the meaning of this piece of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcin) which asks explicitly about the `signal()` function prototype.

Answer (score 10):

Find the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that `[]` and `()` bind before `*`; IOW, `*a[]` is an array of pointers, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function.  Thus,

```
void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int);
```

breaks down as

```
        signal                                          -- signal
        signal(                               )         -- is a function
        signal(    sig                        )         -- with a parameter named sig
        signal(int sig,                       )         --   of type int
        signal(int sig,        handler        )         -- and a parameter named handler
        signal(int sig,       *handler        )         --   which is a pointer
        signal(int sig,      (*handler)(   )) )         --   to a function
        signal(int sig,      (*handler)(int)) )         --   taking an int parameter
        signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) )         --   and returning void
       *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) )         -- returning a pointer
     ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) )(   )    -- to a function
     ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) )(int)    --   taking an int parameter
void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) )(int);   --   and returning void
```

The `signal` function associates a signal (`sig`) with a *callback function* (`handler`), like so:

```
#include <signal.h>

static int interrupt = 0;

/**
 * The following function will be called when a SIGINT is
 * detected (such as when someone types Ctrl-C)
 */
void interrupt_handler( int sig )
{
  interrupt = 1;
}

int main( void )
{
  /**
   * Declare a pointer to the old interrupt handler function
   */
  void (*old_interrupt_handler )(int);

  /**
   * Save the old interrupt handler while setting the new one
   */
  old_interrupt_handler = signal( SIGINT, interrupt_handler );
  while ( !interrupt )
  {
    // do stuff until someone hits Ctrl-C
  };

  /**
   * restore the original interrupt handler
   */
  signal( SIGINT, old_interrupt_handler );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note for people coming across this answer: [you would probably want `sigaction` instead of `signal`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/232711/912144).

Answer (score 9):

The whole thing declares a function called `signal`:

- `signal` takes an int and a function pointer

  - this function pointer takes an `int` and returns `void`
- `signal` returns a function pointer

  - this function pointer **takes an `int`** and returns a `void`

That's where the last `int` comes in.

---

You can use [the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to make sense of such declarations, or the program `cdecl(1)`.

Comment: +1 for informing about `cdecl` and [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) . Looks like an awesome tool

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out in an answer to another recent question, one way to understand these declarations is to swap parameter lists and array declarators with the thing to their left and then read the declaration backwards. In this case that gives you

```
void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int)
```

->

```
void (int)( *(int sig, void (int)(*handler))signal )
```

Which reads as "`signal is a function that takes two parameters and returns a pointer to a function that takes an int parameter and returns void". The two parameters are an int (sig) and a pointer (handler) to a function that takes an int parameter and returns void.

Or you can do the swapping mentally, which is the same as the spiral rule.

Answer (score 0):

`void (*handler)(int);` handler is pointer to a function (say Fn1) with return type `void`and  takes an `int`

`void (*signal(int sig, Fn1)) (int);`

`(*signal(int sig, Fn1);` This function has return type `void` and takes an `int` and `function pointer` as arguments.

The return type of this function, whose pointer is `signal` is possibly a function pointer for a function that takes an `int`[final `int`] with return type `void`

Answer (score 0):

The above prototype can be written as::

```
typedef void (*sig_t) (int);

sig_t signal(int sig, sig_t handler);
```

Now, I hope it would be clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

it is a function returning a pointer to a function returning void..Source:" Unscrambling C Declarations " in DEEP C SECRETS

Comment: A side note: If you ever get to read _Deep C Secrets_, bear in mind that the book is extremely old, and most of its rants aren't valid even in C89.