# Get confused with this declaration - int (*(*foo)(double))[3]

Tags: c++

I am lost in this declaration - `int (*(*foo)(double))[3];`

My understanding is that this is an array with size 3 which element is a function pointer taking double and returning pointer to int. However, the correct explanation seems to be "pointer to function taking double and returning pointer to array of 3 int". **The returning pointer to array of 3 int confuses me a lot as `int` and `[3]` far apart.**

Why is that? What is the syntax or rule to declare variables like this complex?

Comment: http://www.cdecl.org/

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcin/3706735#3706735 for some guides in the answers.

Comment: @user2485710 They already have the correct answer. They want to know why.

Comment: The part confused me is that how [3] in this declaration will be interpreted.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4.aspx

Comment: Well, `int` and `[3]` aren't that far apart if you consider the bit in parentheses as one "thing". `int a[3];` vs `int (...)[3];`.

Comment: I like to use typedefs to break a declaration like this apart. That doesn't help if you inherited the code though.

Comment: @MarkRansom I seriously doubt you'd find this kind of declaration in real world code. It's practically unmaintainable. My best guess is that this is some kind of homework question.

Comment: @FredOverflow you'd be amazed to discover what you can find in the real world. You're probably right though.

Comment: @MarkRansom And you're *definitely* right about the `typedef`s :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just read from the inside out remembering that postfix array (`[]`) and function "call" (`()`) bind tighter than prefix pointer (`*`):

```
      (*foo)              // foo is a pointer...
      (*foo)(double)      // to a function taking a double...
    (*(*foo)(double))     // returning a pointer...
    (*(*foo)(double))[3]  // to an array of 3...
int (*(*foo)(double))[3]; // ints
```

(To work out where to start you might want to work from the outside in, but you need to read back from the inside out to read the declaration in the conventional order.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use ["clockwise spiral rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

```
      +----------------------------------+
      |  +---------------------------+   |
      |  |   +--------------------+  |   |
      |  |   | +----+             |  |   |
      |  |   | |+--+|             |  |   |
      |  |   | |^  ||             |  |   |
 int  (  *   ( *foo)( double      )  [3 ];
   |  ^  ^   ^ ^   ||             |  |   |
   |  |  |   | +---+|             |  |   |
   |  |  |   +------+             |  |   |
   |  |  +------------------------+  |   |
   |  +------------------------------+   |
   +-------------------------------------+
```

Thus, Identifier `foo`

- is a pointer
- to function taking `double` as argument returning
- pointer to
- array 3
- of int

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error) for the merits of the spiral rule.