# Where in the C++ standard does it specify the right-left (spiral rule) for type declarations?

Tags: c++

I'm already familiar with the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), also sometimes called the right-left rule, to decipher declarations in C and in C++. There are ample questions, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-and-c-declarations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcin) already covering how to use the rule to decipher a type in C or C++. However, where does this rule come from?

Specifically, **where** in the C++ standard (say C++20 for concreteness) does it say that one is supposed to parse something like

```
char const * a[10];
```

as `a` is an "array of 10 pointers to const chars" as given by the right-left rule rather than `a` is a "pointer to an array of 10 const chars" as a left-right rule or other method might imply. Is it stated outright in the standard as a rule, or is it a consequence of some other associativity rules (and if so which ones and where)? I would like to be able to derive the spiral rule from the standard.

Comment: Can you pick one language? The C standard and C++ standard are quite different in structure.

Comment: If I had to pick one, C++20.

Comment: I edited your question so that it only asks about C++. If you want, you can also post another question that is exclusively about C.

Comment: I don't think the rule is in the standard.  I think it doesn't even work all the time in C++.

Comment: The right-hand spiral rule isn't part of either standard -- it's an idiom to help people deduce the correct declaration -- that's all. It comes from a 1994 post to the c-faq newsgroup [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin are you saying it is an implementation detail that is not derivable from the standard (i.e. a compiler could choose to parse it in a different order)? Or are you saying that it is derivable from the standard but it is just not outright stated as a rule.

Comment: I don't have time to look up which section it's in, but you should look at the grammar for declarators. The grammar is unambiguous, so there's no need for additional precedence or associativity rules to disambiguate it.

Comment: [dcl.dcl] have fun reading

Comment: @nullUser - you can derive it from both standards using *Operator Precedence* and the language syntax related to functions -- but there is no section in either standard that addresses deconstructing a declaration to break it down into parts.

Comment: It does not. Rather it has complicated grammar, which can be simplified into easier to remember (although not necessarily correct in all cases) spiral rule.

Comment: @bolov [Here](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl)'s a link

Comment: It's kind of like there is no formal *"King Phillip Came Over From Germany Saturday"* in taxonomy to help remember the order *"Kingdom Phylum Class Order Family Genus Species"* -- but somebody came up with it to make it easier to remember...

Comment: FWIW, Using aliases, and named types kind of makes the rule moot.  For instance, `char const * a[10];` could be replaced with `std::array<std::string,10>` or even `std::array<std::string_view,10>` if you just want a "pointer" to some string.  Yes, it's more typing but I find self documenting code so much easier to work with.

Comment: spiral rule can be considered a "manual" derivative of lexxer algorithm. C++ compilers don't even use that algorithm because syntax became too complex  compared to C and there are multiple possible "extras". Spiral rule works in C++ only where declarations are compatible with (old version of?) C.